# Is Web Worker structured-clone broken in IE11 for Set/Map?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11, web-worker

Seems to me like IE11 is unable to pass Sets/Maps to a Web Worker using postMessage. Structured clone should work for them, according to MDN/caniuse, so is there something wrong with the below I'm missing, or is IE11 broken here?

(Edit: amusingly, stackoverflow snippets don't work with IE11. Check it in the console here https://jsfiddle.net/zt3emy6c/)

```js
var b = new Blob(['self.onmessage=function(e){'+
    'console.log(e.data.q);'+
    'console.log(e.data.q.size);'+
    'postMessage([e.data,new Set(),new Map([[1, "asdf"]])]);}'
], { type: 'application/javascript' });

var worker = new Worker(URL.createObjectURL(b));

worker.addEventListener('message', function(e) { 
    console.log('expected e.data[0].q.size to equal 1, got ' + e.data[0].q.size);
    console.log('expected e.data[1].size to equal 0, got ' + e.data[1].size);
    console.log('expected e.data[2].size to equal 1, got ' + e.data[2].size);
    console.log('expected e.data[2].get to exist, got ' + e.data[2].get);
});

var values = new Set();
values.add('asdf');
worker.postMessage({ q: values });
```

Comment: I think there is any condition applied to the IE browser from this link. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Structured_clone_algorithm That can be the possible cause for this issue. Other than that I did not get any documentation that can give information about this issue.